# Parameterization of a rhombus

Tags: differential-geometry

The graph of curve $|x|+|y|=1 $ is a rhombus, How can I obtain a parameterization in a counterclockwise sense in such a way that it can be expressed as the curve $\alpha:I\subset R\to R^2 $,$\alpha (t)=(x(t),y(t))$ ?

Comment: You'll need to parametrize the four line segments individually.

Comment: Just use a piece-wise function. You can't really do it any other way.

Comment: Why do you call "rhombus" a square ?

Answer (score 3):

If one uses the unit step function

\begin{equation}
u(t)=\begin{cases}0\text{ for }t<0\\1\text{ for }t\ge0\end{cases}
\end{equation}

then

\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= 1-t+2(t-2)u(t-2) \\
y(t) &= t+2(1-t)u(t-1)+2(t-3)u(t-3)
\end{aligned}
for $0 \leq t \leq 4$.

The only advantage with this version is constant speed.

[Desmos animation of constant speed rhombus](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lhfdqboeuc)

[image: Animation]

Comment: Very cool. I guess $u$ should be $U$ or vice versa :)

Comment: @TedShifrin  Correct, will fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ted's suggestion is probably best for computation, but
$$
\left.
\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= \cos t |\cos t| \\
y(t) &= \sin t |\sin t|
\end{aligned}
\right\}
\qquad 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi,
$$
does the job.

Comment: Oh, very clever. But *ugh*. :)

Comment: @Ted: On the plus side, one deduces a real-analytic parametrization, for each odd positive integer $p$, of $|x|^{2/p} + |y|^{2/p} = 1$. :)

Comment: Very cool. Upvoted it earlier.